# Opening Chrome icon flashes up then disappears

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome

A friend has just downloaded and installed Chrome for Mac OS (current version 51).

When they click to open Chrome the icon appears briefly in the dock, then disappears and Chrome closes.

The behavior is replicated if you try to launch Chrome form the command line using

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

They get an error

```
Failed to create /Users/NAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/SingletonLock
```

If they run with `sudo` they are able to start Chrome.

```
sudo /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

How can we fix this? We've tried reinstalling Chrome and the problem persists.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please give us a little more detail about the error (if you can). Post the text of the error.

Answer (score 1):

We fixed this by deleting the lock file in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/SingletonLock` and everything else in the profile running

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome
```

Seems related to the [Chrome is not opening](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qImqA8Tt2HQ) on the Google Chrome Help forum.